# Can I style the active state of an option when it's selected and disabled using react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Check this out:

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-iowp4e?file=/example.tsx)

[image]

The `blue` option is `disabled`. But it has been selected in a previous interaction when that option was `enabled`. But now I need to make it `disabled` and force the user to choose something else (by using form validation).

The fact is that the color I'm using for the selected state (like the dark blue in the example) does not combine well with the `grey` color for the disabled label).

So I would like to customize the selected state color (the dark blue), specifically for the case when the option is disabled.

I still want the normal dark blue to show on selected options that are enabled and selected.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've ended up doing:

```
<ReactSelect
  // OTHER PROPS
  styles={{
    option: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      backgroundColor:
        state.isSelected && state.isDisabled ? '#SOME_COLOR' : base.backgroundColor,
    }),
  }}
/>
```